# Most efficient way to communicate between 1 phone and 2 tablets at close distance?

Tags: java, android, networking, bluetooth, client-server

The plateform is Android 4.+

- I have 1 phone playing the role of server and 2 tablets as clients
- The tablets are at a distance < 5-10m from the server, in the same room
- My goal is to have the phone launch a game between the two tablets, and monitor what is going on (like a game master)
- There will be many exchange of data from/to the phone which command a robot by bluetooth (already paired and managed by an independent app and SDK, i don't have the sources of that part)

---

[image: Diagram]

---

For the communication protocole I'm thinking of using [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) which appear to be nice.

For the "how" I can't decide which one is best between these two:

- [**Bluetooth**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

OR

- [**Wi-Fi P2P**](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)

Which one should i use in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the amount of bandwidth that is required by the particular game. In most cases, Bluetooth will be perfectly fine. It has the advantage of having a lower power requirement. If you are streaming audio or video data, go for WiFi.

XMPP is unnecessarily complex for a game. Have you looked at [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)?

Comment: Is this behavior possible with bluetooth :  Launch each application in each devices, automatically launch de peers detection. The application launched on the phone will initiate automatically the pairing as server and the 2 others will respond as client (automatically by their names) ?

Comment: At startup, the clients would start looking for a server until they find out. The server listens for clients until there are enough to start a game.

Comment: When communicating with several devices i must use one BluetoothSocket per device (from server point of view) ?

Comment: I opted for bluetooth and I will try FlatBuffers thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this project as you explained. I would use bluetooth - but there is always pros and cons:

Bluetooth Pros:

- Super easy to implement.
- Literary simulates the serial port, sends the string and interprets it.

Bluetooth Cons:

- Not as reliable as Wifi.
- Not all devices have bluetooth. But almost every tablet/phone has Wifi.
- If not used properly, you can jam up the socket and need to reconnect.
- One bluetooth server can feed up to 7 devices. Wifi direct (AS FAR AS I KNOW) has no limitation on the number of connections (But it slows down after 5 connections or so)

---

Having said all this, I am not sure what is the role of server in your application. If the project is as you drawn, I would only use the two tablets and get rid of the middle man (the phone)... Unless, there are other reasons behind it.

---

A very easy to understand Bluetooth implementation [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stream the game on the phone Wi-fi P2P is the best but what I got from this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) it's available for android 4.0 and later.

> Using these APIs, you can discover and connect to other devices when
>   each device supports Wi-Fi P2P, then communicate over a speedy
>   connection across distances much longer than a Bluetooth connection.
>   This is useful for applications that share data among users, such as a
>   multiplayer game or a photo sharing application.

If you want to monitor the game with strings you'd better use Bluetooth. I don't know about 10 meters but I'm sure Bluetooth works fine in less than 10 meters.

Comment: You got a point here, i only want to send simple informations like Strings et integers